# How write a CSV in R that is correctly read by Google Spreadsheets

Tags: r, csv, google-sheets

### Problem

I am trying to write a dataframe to a CSV-file that will be read-in correctly by Google Spreadsheets however I am running into an error with a particular column format.

There is one column called 'details' that has values that look like this `{\"campaign_id\":1,\"line_item_id\":1234}`. This column format is correctly read by R from an original dataframe supplied from Google Spreadsheets but when written into a CSV, the column is separated along the `,` into two columns pushing overwriting the values of the following column (which is empty by default).

### Data

The dataframe in R looks like this:

```
data <- structure(
  list(
    `Line Item Id` = c(1234, 4567),
    Details = c(
      "{\"campaign_id\":1,\"line_item_id\":1234}",
      "{\"campaign_id\":1,\"line_item_id\":4567}"
    ),
    `Bid Strategy Type` = c("",""),
    `TrueView Video Ad Formats` = c("In-stream / Video Discovery",
                                    "In-stream / Video Discovery"),
    `TrueView Bid Strategy Type` = c("Manual CPV",
                                     "Manual CPV")
  ),
  row.names = 1:2,
  class = "data.frame"
)
```

### Current approach

I have tried writing the relevant column in a quote:

library(tidyverse)

```
data %>%
  mutate(Details = dQuote(Details,q = )) %>%
  write.csv("test.csv", fileEncoding = "UTF-8",na = "",row.names = FALSE,quote = FALSE)
```

But this does not seem to work and neither does omitting the `dQuote`.

My output csv is this:

[test.csv generated by above code](https://file.io/cXP1exwT8jKz)

### More Details

The data being wrangled here is an SDF generated by DV360 a Google platform to manage YouTube ad campaigns. In my process I download an SDF from DV360 change some values in R and upload it back. However re-uploading does not work at the moment due to the described problem. I have tested it to confirm that the column problem described above is causing the issue and if manually corrected uploading works.

### Expected output

I have added the expected output and the output I am getting.

What I have at the moment:

```
Line Item Id,Details,TrueView Video Ad Formats,TrueView Bid Strategy Type
14596716402,“{"campaign_id":283,"line_item_id":99588}”,In-stream / Video Discovery,
14596725552,“{"campaign_id":283,"line_item_id":99585}”,In-stream / Video Discovery,
```

What I need:

```
Line Item Id,Details,TrueView Video Ad Formats,TrueView Bid Strategy Type
1234,"{""campaign_id"":1,""line_item_id"":1234}",,In-stream / Video Discovery
4567,"{""campaign_id"":1,""line_item_id"":4567}",,In-stream / Video Discovery
```

And quite interestingly, what I get when I fiex the problem by hand in googlesheets and then download the file:

```
Line Item Id,Details,TrueView Video Ad Formats,TrueView Bid Strategy Type
1234,"""{""""campaign_id"""":1,""""line_item_id"""":1234}""",,In-stream / Video Discovery
4567,"""{""""campaign_id"""":1,""""line_item_id"""":4567}""",,In-stream / Video Discovery
```

Comment: Have you considered simply using the [**`googlesheets4`**](https://googlesheets4.tidyverse.org/) and [**`googledrive`**](https://googledrive.tidyverse.org/) packages, which is integrated into the [**`tidyverse`**](https://www.tidyverse.org/)?

Comment: So you tried `write.csv(data, "test.csv", row.names=FALSE)` and that didn't work? How exactly are you reading it with google sheets? If I take the output from the command I wrote and drag it into Google Drive it opens in sheets correctly.

Comment: @Greg no because I didn't know that existed. If that works I am both hugely thankful and humbled^^

Comment: @Fnguyen Happy to help! See [this link](https://www.tidyverse.org/packages/) for a list of the packages integrated into or compatible with the **`tidyverse`**.

Comment: @MrFlick the command does of course write a CSV. But as said it will split the details column along the comma and write the values afterwards into the next column.

Comment: @Fnguyen When I tried it, it did not split those columns. What exactly are you doing with the csv file after you create it? I can't reproduce the issue.

Comment: @Greg unfortunately this does not work after testing because I need to write the csv to local storage as a csv not directly into googlesheets.

Comment: @MrFlick there are no more steps. If I use the exact data posted here and the exact method posted and then open the resulting csv-file in spreadsheets it will push the ``\"line_item_id\":1234}`` part of the details-column into the Bid Strategy type column. My pc has German local settings but I use write.csv with sep = ``,`` and Dv360 has US locale when uploading as does spreadsheets.

Comment: @Fnguyen Sorry to hear that.  Maybe try adjusting the [`qmethod`](https://rdrr.io/r/utils/write.table.html#heading-2) parameter for `write.csv()`?  **Also, are you allowed to use a _tab_-delimited `.tsv` file in place of a `.csv`?**  If so, then [`write.table()`](https://rdrr.io/r/utils/write.table.html) with `sep = "\t"` should do the trick.  I've always preferred TSVs because (in my experience) tabs are rarer in datasets than commas...

Comment: @Greg I tried this as well but both ``escape`` and ``double`` do not work. I do not know exactly which value to supply to ``qmethod``.

Comment: @MrFlick you can find the result file generated by my code here: https://file.io/cXP1exwT8jKz

Comment: @Fnguyen It's still not clear how you are getting the file into Sheets, are you using File> Import or just dragging it over? I admit when  you import it, it may look like the columns overlap, but you just need to resize the columns to see that Bid Strategy Type is in fact empty.

Comment: @MrFlick Perhaps the issue is with Google Sheets reading the file, and not with `write.csv()` in generating it?

Comment: @Fnguyen I'm afraid I don't have time at the moment to do anything more than make suggestions, but have you considered my [suggestion here](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/comments/123251363) to save as a `.tsv` rather than a `.csv`?

Comment: @Fnguyen the file you posted looks like it was made with `quote=FALSE`. That's not what I suggested. Use `write.csv(data, "test.csv", row.names=FALSE)`

Comment: @MrFlick I can easily validate that this isn't a representation issue but in fact the values being split. If I inspect each column I can see the values being split and in two columns. I agree that ``write.csv`` does not fail to write a valid csv. The output is correctly recognized by R, Excel, etc. However I need to be able to upload this file into Google ecosystem (DV360, Spreadsheets) and is not doing that. Seeing as I cannot change how Google receives the file I have to change how I write it.

Comment: Show the raw text of the csv file that you are importing. And then show the raw text of the file you are writing. (Don't upload to external sites, just put the text in the question itself). That will make it easy to see if the same quote escaping is being used. I don't know what "SDF" or "DV360" but since I can't reproduce the problem with Sheets directly, it seems the problem must be there. Do they have any documentation on expected file formats?

Comment: @MrFlick I have added the raw text in the post as you said. I can already see that my code outputs a different style of doublequote than expected but I do not know why that is. But this will help for sure.

Comment: @MrFlick thanks to your help / comments I have solved it. I will post the solution now.

Comment: @Greg I have solved it thanks to your help and MrFlick, I will post the solution.

Answer (score 1):

After getting valuable input from @Greg and @MrFlick I was finally able to solve it.

For Google ecosystem (Spreadsheets and Dv360) to correctly read the column it needs to have this format:

```
"{""campaign_id"":1,""line_item_id"":1234}"
```

Using `dQuote()` will put the necessary quotes around the column but due to my system settings, the wrong quote type was supplied. So we need to put off `useFancyQuotes`.

Additionally the already occuring quotes around `campaign_id` and `line_item_id` need to be double-quoted.

Maybe there is a faster way but the following code will work:

```
library(dplyr) # only needed for pipe, not part of solution

options(useFancyQuotes = FALSE)  

data %>%
  mutate(Details = dQuote(gsub('"','""',Details))) %>%
  write.csv("test3.csv", fileEncoding = "UTF-8",na = "",row.names = FALSE,quote = FALSE)
```

So we need to first convert all quotes to double Quotes, which I did with `gsub()` and then use `dQuote()` to put final quotes around the column making sure not to use fancy, directional quotes.